# Understanding Feynman parameterization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization), it gives the Feynman parametrization formula as
$$\frac{1}{A_1\cdots A_n} = (n-1)!\int_0^1 du_1\cdots \int_0^1 du_n \frac{\delta(1-\sum_{k=1}^n u_k)}{(\sum_{k=1}^n u_kA_k)^n} 
\\ = (n-1)!\int_0^1 du_1\int_0^{1-u_1} du_2 \cdots \int_0^{1-u_1 \cdots - u_{n-2}} du_{n-1} \frac{1}{[A_1 + u_1(A_2 - A_1) + \cdots + u_{n-1}(A_n - A_1)]^n}$$

I am trying to understand how the second line follows from the first, in particular the integrand and the upper limits of integration.

Since we have $\delta(1-\sum_{k=1}^n u_k)$ this implies the outermost integral collapses and we have $u_n = 1 - u_1 \cdots - u_{n-1}$. But wouldn't this instead imply that
$$\int_0^1 du_1\cdots \int_0^1 du_n \frac{\delta(1-\sum_{k=1}^n u_k)}{(\sum_{k=1}^n u_kA_k)^n}  \\= \int_0^1 du_1\int_0^{1-u_1} du_2 \cdots \int_0^{1-u_1 \cdots - u_{n-2}} du_{n-1} \frac{1}{[A_n + u_1(A_2 - A_n) + \cdots + u_{n-1}(A_{n-1} - A_n)]^n}$$

Further down on the Wikipedia page under the Derivation section it seems that they have the above formula. Is the formula they have under the "Formula" section incorrect?

Also, how does the $\delta$ function in the integrand change the upper limits of integration?

Comment: Have you tried the case $n=1$ or $n=2$ yet?

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yes, for $n = 2$ I get $u_2 = 1 - u_1$, and so $\int_0^1 du_1 1/(u_1A_1 + (1-u_1)A_2)) = \int_0^1 du_1 1/(A_2 + u_1(A_1 - A_2))$, which does not agree with the first formula and does not change any of the bounds.